# Edit data with bootstrap modal 3 not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to edit the data with bootstrap modal, but when I run the script I created, click event does not work. I expect the modal to appear with specific data according to the "dataProduct" attribute.

This source code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-idProduct="<?= $data['id_product'] ?>" class="edit-dataProduct btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Product</h4>
        </div>
        <form id="form-add" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body edit-modal">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <input type="submit" name="editProduct" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Product">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
$("#table_products").on('click', '.edit-dataProduct' ,function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.get('http://localhost/market/member/detail_product.php?id_product='+$(this).attr('data-idProduct'), function(data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
    });

        $("#modalEdit").modal('show');

});
```

and than, this is php script:

```
<?php

$id_product = $_GET['id_product'];

$conn = new MySQLi('localhost','root','','marketplace'); 

$sql    = "SELECT products.*, categories.name AS category FROM products, categories WHERE products.id_cat = categories.id_cat AND products.id_product='".$id_product."'";
$query  = $conn->query($sql);
$data   = $query->fetch_assoc();

?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="id_product" name="id_product" readonly value="<?= $id_product ?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?= $data['name'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Size</label>
        <input type="text" id="size" name="size" value="<?= $data['size'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stock</label>
        <input type="number" id="stock" name="stock" value="<?= $data['stock'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Categories</label>
        <select id="id_cat" name="id_cat" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">-- Categories --</option>
            <?php if ($data['id_cat'] == 1) { ?>
            <option value="1" selected>Batik Tulis</option>
            <option value="2">Batik Cap</option>
            <option value="3">Batik Printing</option>
            <?php }else if ($data['id_cat'] == 2) { ?>
            <option value="1">Batik Tulis</option>
            <option value="2" selected>Batik Cap</option>
            <option value="3">Batik Printing</option>
            <?php }else if ($data['id_cat'] == 3) { ?>
            <option value="1">Batik Tulis</option>
            <option value="2">Batik Cap</option>
            <option value="3" selected>Batik Printing</option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Equity</label>
        <input type="number" id="equity" name="equity" value="<?= $data['equity'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="number" id="price" name="price" value="<?= $data['price'] ?>" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Zip Code &amp; Phone Number</label>
        <input type="file" name="images" id="images">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="id_user" name="id_user" value="<?= $data['id_user'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="old_images" name="old_images" value="<?= $data['images'] ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="<?= $data['images'] ?>" alt="<?= $data['name'] ?>" class="img-responsive" style="width: 75%;margin: auto;">
</div>
</div>
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: Does anything change if you omit `action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"`?

Comment: "Does not work" does not describe what you expect and what is actually happening, so it is not a useful problem description.

Comment: My problem is when i will show bootstrap modal. Modal not showing. @AndersLindén

Comment: Do you include the bootstrap javascript file?

Comment: Also, you could easily post what the console is reporting when you try to open the modal.

Comment: Yes i do, the error reporting `TypeError: $ is undefined` on the line `$.get('http://localhost/market/member/detail_product.php?id_product='+$(this).attr('data-idProduct'), function(data) {` @AndersLindén

Comment: So you did not include jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("#table_products").on('click', '.edit-dataProduct' ,function(event) {` I think you just need to make it `$(document.body).on('click','.edit-dataProduct', function(event){`

Comment: Sorry, I'd say the click listener scope is wrong, that's why I suggest changing it to the above, but can you see in your browser console if the click is sending the AJAX request?  That would help you pinpoint if the issue is with the click listener or somewhere in the request.  I agree with "Anders", please provide more description to the issue than "not working".

Comment: I expect the modal to appear with specific data according to the "dataProduct" attribute.

Comment: Ok, but first can you tell if your click listener is firing?  After event.preventDefault();  if you put console.log('Click Fires!'); does this show in your browser console?  If so, then we at least know the AJAX is firing.  And if the AJAX is firing, is it reaching the URL or do you get a 404?  if we know it's reaching the URL, then what data is it receiving?...

Comment: i got the console, but when i try to use `$.get(....)` i get `TypeError: $ is undefined`

Comment: that's a symptom of jQuery loading after your script OR you're using jQuery in no conflict mode.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/  

jQuery can't be called with the dollar signs if it's not loaded first.